# How do I find the area bounded by the surfaces in this example?

Tags: integration, surfaces

Calculate areas of shapes bounded by curves

The expression is given

$\frac{(2x+3y-5)^2}{16} + \frac{(3x-2y+1)^2}{25} = 1$

Wanted through $s = \int \int dxdy$, but somehow the limits are not entirely clear.

I decided to make a replacement
$u = 2x+3y-5\\v = 3x-2y+1$

Then expressed

$x = \frac{1}{13}*(2u+3v+7) \\y = \frac{1}{13}*(3u-2v+17)$

Found partial derivatives for Jacobian and found Jacobian

$J = |\frac{1}{13}|$

Then he moved to the polar coordinates
$u = 4rcos(\phi)\\ v=5rsin(\phi)$

And after the substitution, everything was reduced to $r = 1$

And now I'm stupid and I don’t know whether to set the limits for the integral or write something else ...

I can’t solve it.

Comment: You almost had it, basically what happens is that the integral became $\frac{1}{13}\iint_{S'} 1 dudv$ where $S'$ was an ellipse with semimajor and semiminor axes $5$ and $4$. The integral $\iint_D 1 dA = \text{Area}(D)$, so in this case it evaluates to $\frac{20\pi}{13}$ from the $\pi ab$ formula. This is an extremely standard conceptual trick you have to keep you in your toolbox from now on.

Comment: Yes, I also succeeded with this trick, but in the textbook the answer is $\frac{208pi}{169}$

Comment: Another trick, it took a long time to solve for $x$ and $y$ from $u$ and $v$, but that was unnecessary for calculating the Jacobian. The other common trick is to calculate the inverse Jacobian, i.e. the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ w.r.t. $x$ and $y$. From the first set of equations, we easily get that $J^{-1} = |-4 - 9| = 13$. Then use the property that $J^{-1} = \frac{1}{J}$.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say other than that the problem here as you have written does not equal $\frac{208\pi}{169}$. Maybe check the textbook problem again for other details or a mistype on this post or the problem?

Comment: I don’t even know, everything seems to be true, maybe the textbook is incorrect

Comment: thank you, I will ask the teacher